# Bundle install not work on rvm + ruby2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundle

after install RVM and ruby2.0.0, running

```
$ bundle install
```

just get nothing response and halt. How can i track where have the problem?

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'rails', '4.0.0
```

trying to list:

```
    $ bundle list
    Gems included by the bundle:
    * actionmailer (4.0.0)
    * actionpack (4.0.0)
    * activemodel (4.0.0)
    * activerecord (4.0.0)
    * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    * activesupport (4.0.0)
    * arel (4.0.0)
    * atomic (1.1.14)
    * builder (3.1.4)
    * bundler (1.3.5)
    * erubis (2.7.0)
    * hike (1.2.3)
    * i18n (0.6.5)
    * mail (2.5.4)
    * mime-types (1.25)
    * minitest (4.3.2)
    * multi_json (1.8.0)
    * polyglot (0.3.3)
    * rack (1.5.2)
    * rack-test (0.6.2)
    * rails (4.0.0)
    * railties (4.0.0)
    * rake (10.1.0)
    * sprockets (2.10.0)
    * sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
    * thor (0.18.1)
    * thread_safe (0.1.3)
    * tilt (1.4.1)
    * treetop (1.4.15)
    * tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

I install RVM in my home directory without sudo. I even do rvm implode and re-install and just rvm install 2.0.0 and the bundle command halt.

```
$ rvm info

ruby-2.0.0-p247:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "redhat/6/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "23 hours 31 minutes 28 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/liangji/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    ruby:         "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/liangji/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/liangji/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/home/liangji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    IRBRC:        "/home/liangji/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: I have sometimes found `bundle install` can take 5 or 10 minutes doing *something* (not bothered to try finding out what, but suspect collecting gem metadata online). How long have you waited?

Comment: waiting for 30 minutes and longer and still nothing response, until press CTRL-C to break.

Comment: the file Gemfile.lock created after bundle list. but if i deleted Gemfile.lock, it cannot generate Gemfile.lock after bundle install is running and nothing happen after CTRL-C to break.

Comment: Please do `rvm info` ensure that the information makes sense.  Potentially post it here.  Also report here how you installed RVM.  Did you use `sudo` during any steps, or did you change to root user at any point.

Comment: i run `rvm implode` and `rm ~/.rvm -rf` manually. and re-install rvm. and just run `rvm install 2.0.0`. and `rvm --default use 2.0.0`. But it still halt after trying `bundle install` in an empty directory, even not prompt for "Gemfile not exists". I pasted `rvm info` above.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man! it works now. I think maybe the only step used sudo is `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`. I don't run the command this time.